# Checking for duplicates in array

Tags: templating, assets, image

I'm trying to remove duplicate image objects from an array, but can't figure out why it won't find it:

```
{% for image in product.productGallery %}
    {% set productGalleryArray = productGalleryArray|merge([image]) %}
{% endfor %}

{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% set variantImage = variant.productVariantImage.first() %}
    {% if variantImage|length and variantImage not in productGalleryArray %}
        {% set productGalleryArray = productGalleryArray|merge([variantImage]) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% if productGalleryArray|length %}
    <div class="slideshow">
        {% for image in productGalleryArray %}
            <img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a `productGallery` field which you can add images to, but also add an image to the product variant via `productVariantImage`.

This can cause the issue where by theres duplicate of the same image being output from the slideshow after it's merged the two fields together.

So I need to ideally:

- Remove the duplicates before the array is merged, OR
- Find and remove duplicates after the array is merged (Via a Twig filter?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're checking correctly with `{% if variantImage not in productGalleryArray %}` (this should check if `variantImage` isn't already in the array), but your code doesn't seem to set a `productGalleryArray` array in the global scope. Variables initially set inside `for` loops are scoped only to that `for` loop.

So I think you just need to declare an empty array at the top of your code *outside* and *before* the first `for` loop:

```
{% set productGalleryArray = [] %}
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably should have added this array to the question, as this is already in there. So I'm still having the issue :(